# Can you overwrite the batch size set in SessionFactoryOptions?

Tags: java, hibernate, sessionfactory

Consider the code below, would this overwrite the batch_size configured for the sessionFactory to 25 or will there be some conflict because the batch_size configuration doesn't match the code?

```
//this prints: "Config batch_size: 100"
System.out.println("Config batch_size: "+sessionFactory.getSessionFactoryOptions().getJdbcBatchSize());
int batchSize = 25;
int batchCount = 0;
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
for (Users user : users) {
    session.update(user);
    batchCount++;
    if (batchCount % batchSize == 0) {
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implemented loop and hibernate.jdbc.batch_size operates on different levels.

Your loop operates on entities (of your choice). But a single User might need multiple inserts (for example, when a User has multiple Adresses). 
All these inserts get executed as (25 insertions) single inserts with your loop approach. 
The flush and clear just prevent the session to grow without limit.

hibernate.jdbc.batch_size on the other hand will bundle (insertion)statements that are identical and only differ 
in in the parameter values into a single statement, with a list of parameter sets. 
The execution of such a batched statement should be processed much more efficient by the database
then the equivalent single statements.

it will send 25 queries at a time (going by the code) and also 
send 100 queries at a time (going by the configuration) but at different level.
I hope Makes sense.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was trying to understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you want insert 1000 records and configured batch_size=20 as below .means send "batch size" number of queries together in one go instead of sending each query as the code fires the query. Therefore in this case there will be 1000 insert queries, sent 50 times with 20 insert queries in each batch.

property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20"

put logger org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch in level debug. 
hibernate can generate batches with size 1,2 or 3 in case of wrong order of inserts. 
try to use hibernate.order_inserts=true hibernate.order_updates=true

Comment: I am aware of how to set the batch_size property. I have my batch size configured to "hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="100". My question is, if I have the batch_size configured to 100, but I implement the above code to flush/clear every 25 inserts, what will happen? Will it send 100 queries at a time (going by the configuration) or 25 queries at a time (going by the code)?

Comment: I have posted new Answer.hope it may clear your confusion.